# ¿Por qué en este código no puedo aumentar la cantidad de iteraciones del bucle while?

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando a incursionar en JavaScript y empezando a hacer algunos ejercicios. Se me dio por intentar resolver el siguiente problema:

**Un amigo llamado Cofla se ha ganado la lotería y quiere hacer una gran fiesta para celebrarlo.
Busca un programador para que le diseñe una aplicación con la cual pueda hacer control de las personas
que entran a su fiesta.
Las condiciones para el diseño son las siguientes:
-La fiesta tiene una capacidad máxima de 30 personas.
-La fiesta abre sus puertas a las 2 am y cierra a las 7 am.
-No se permite la entrada a menores de 18 años.
-La primera persona en entrar después de las 2 am, entra gratis.
-Las entrada cuestan 1000 pesos.
-El programa debe hacer un registro de la cantidad de personas que van entrando, con orden de llegada, hora de llegada y nombre del invitado.
-El programa debe hacer el conteo de la cantidad de dinero recaudado.**

A continuación describo cómo intenté resolverlo. El problema que estoy teniendo es que no estoy logrando hacer qel ciclo while que llama a la función validarInvitado haga  las iteraciones hasta que personasDentro sea menor que 30. Por alguna razón se tilda la máquina si defino ese límite en 20 o más, pero si le pongo un límite de 10 funciona perfecto.

Alguno sabe cómo optimizar recursos en este código? Cualquier otra sugerencia será bienvenida. Gracias!

```
const aleatorio = (min,max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
}

let listaNombres = ["Cristian","Cesar","Francisco","Romy","Juan","Antonia","Julian","Pisu","María","Romeo","Karol","Constancio","Melany","Bela","Silvestre","CR7","Jorge","Domingo","Mariana","Franco","David","Hasdy","Taufit","Andres","Sofia","Evelia","Margot","Sebas","Nicho","Joche","Armando"];

const nombreAleatorio = () => {
    let ind = aleatorio(0,30);
    return listaNombres[ind];
}

let listaInvitados = [];
let personasDentro = 0;
let dineroRecaudado = 0;
let i = 0;
let time = 1;

const validarInvitado = () => {

    if (listaInvitados[i][2] < 2 || listaInvitados[i][2] > 7) {
        document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. No estaba dentro del horario de entrada. <br>`);
    }
    else {
        if (listaInvitados[i][1] >= 18){
            if (personasDentro == 0){
                document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. ENTRÓ PRIMERO Y GRATIS. <br>`);
                personasDentro++;
            }
            else {
                document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. ENTRÓ PAGANDO ENTRADA. <br>`);
                personasDentro++;
                dineroRecaudado += 1000;
            }
        }
        else {
            document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. No pudo entrar por ser menor de edad. <br>`);
        }
    }

}

while (personasDentro < 10) {
    listaInvitados[i] = [`Cliente ${i}`,aleatorio(12,30),time,nombreAleatorio()];
    validarInvitado();
    i++;
    time += 0.25;
}
document.write(`<br><br>Entraron ${personasDentro} personas y se recaudaron ${dineroRecaudado} ARS.`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Después de un largo análisis, me he dado cuenta de que el error provenía de la variable **time**. Lo que está ocurriendo es que debido a que son valores aleatorios puede que nunca se lleguen a acumular 30 personas dentro del establecimiento antes de las 7 de la mañana. Por ello como la variable **personasDentro** nunca va a llegar a 30, se queda colgado. He modificado algo el programa para poder tener esto en cuenta.

En primer lugar he divido el primer if en dos para que si ya son más de las 7 que devuelva un 2 y salga del while para que no se quede en un bucle infinito.

```
if (listaInvitados[i][2] < 2) {
      document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. No estaba dentro del horario de entrada. <br>`);
          return 0;
}
if (listaInvitados[i][2] > 7){
      document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. No estaba dentro del horario de entrada. <br>`);
          return 2;
}
```

De resto lo único diferente que he hecho es que en lugar de sumar la variable **personasDentro** en cada if, devuelvo 0 (si no se suma), 1 (si se suma) o 2 (si ya se paso la hora). También he creado una variable **limit** de tipo booleano para controlar el while. Te muestro como ha quedado el código final.

```js
const aleatorio = (min,max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
}

let listaNombres = ["Cristian","Cesar","Francisco","Romy","Juan","Antonia","Julian","Pisu","María","Romeo","Karol","Constancio","Melany","Bela","Silvestre","CR7","Jorge","Domingo","Mariana","Franco","David","Hasdy","Taufit","Andres","Sofia","Evelia","Margot","Sebas","Nicho","Joche","Armando"];

const nombreAleatorio = () => {
    let ind = aleatorio(0,30);
    return listaNombres[ind];
}

let listaInvitados = [];
let personasDentro = 0;
let dineroRecaudado = 0;
let i = 0;
let time = 1;
var limit = true;

const validarInvitado = () => {

    if (listaInvitados[i][2] < 2) {
        document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. No estaba dentro del horario de entrada. <br>`);
          return 0;
    }
    if (listaInvitados[i][2] > 7){
      document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. No estaba dentro del horario de entrada. <br>`);
          return 2;
    }
    else {
        if (listaInvitados[i][1] >= 18){
            if (personasDentro == 0){
                document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. ENTRÓ PRIMERO Y GRATIS. <br>`);
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. ENTRÓ PAGANDO ENTRADA. <br>`);
                dineroRecaudado += 1000;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            document.write(`El ${listaInvitados[i][0]} se llama ${listaInvitados[i][3]}, tiene ${listaInvitados[i][1]} años de edad y llegó a las ${listaInvitados[i][2]}. No pudo entrar por ser menor de edad. <br>`);
            return 0;
        }
    }

}

while (limit) {
    listaInvitados[i] = [`Cliente ${i}`,aleatorio(12,30),time,nombreAleatorio()];
    var result = validarInvitado();
    if (result == 1){
      personasDentro++;
    }
    if (result == 2){
      break;
    }
    if(personasDentro == 30){
      limit = false;
    }
    i++;
    time += 0.25;
}
document.write(`<br><br>Entraron ${personasDentro} personas y se recaudaron ${dineroRecaudado} ARS.`);
```

Lo dicho, debido a la variable **time** es posible que no siempre entren 30 personas en el local. Además, si abre a la 1 y cierra a las 7, aunque todos entren al local, es imposible llegar a 30, si cada uno entre cada 0,25. Cualquier duda me comentas.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda Taehyung95! Me fue muy útil. Para aportarte algo también, luego volví al código y me di cuenta que si en el while original que yo había puesto, además de la condición de `(personasDentro <10)`, se le agrega `(personasDentro < 10 && time < 7)`, se soluciona también el problema. En ese caso podrías aumentar la cantidad de personasDentro a cualquier número, y podrías aumentar el tiempo en pasos más pequeños. Saludos!